# Basic Beamer Footer

Tags: beamer

I need to add a footer in my beamer consisting of:
1. My name (left side)
2. Title (middle)
3. Slide number (right side)

Very basic, no sort of theme.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If so, please post the code you have so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that, I took a source of one of beamer themes and changed (it is enough to copy that to the beginning of the beamer document) to something like

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}%{infolines theme}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.25\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]   {author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.50\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
   \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.25\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
 \vskip0pt%
}
```